# Mule Server 3.6 > Anypoint Studio > Request Connector

Tags: json, post, mule, esb, mule-studio

How do I set the Request Connector to send Raw JSON data using POST method?

On my Set Payload transformer I have this:

```
#[{ "productId": #[sessionVars.productId] }]
```

When I run my Mule App, I get the following error:

```
Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: String
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding

```
 <set-variable variableName="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
```

just above your http request endpoint.

For more details have a look [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Request+Connector#HTTPRequestConnector-customparameters)

Let me know if this works for you.